# Asp.net core 3.1 Replace Slash (/) by question Marq (?) in the Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In an Asp.net core 3.1 we want to configure the routing.

We have a GetDepart action

```
[HttpGet("GetDepart/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Depart>> GetDepart(int id)
{
    //Return a Department
}
```

> How to configure routing to replace slashes (/) with question Mark (?)
> In Url,

therefore instead of having **http://localhost:44339/Departs/GetDepart/1**, we want to have **http://localhost:44339/Departs/GetDepart ?id=1**

Comment: You replace a / with a ? for example by using`string.Replace("/", "?");` But that's not what you're looking for here. Maybe this can help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca2535/query-string-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: @Jelle that link has nothing specific to this question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The article is split in two, I should've send the second part straight away: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/pass-parameter-or-query-string-in-action-method-in-Asp-Net-m/

Comment: @Jelle the first article is about WebForms and doesn't really talk about query strings except in isolated snippets. Most of it is just describes creating a WebForms form with a couple of fields

Comment: @Jelle, the question is about the routing in Asp.net core web api, i need to have "?" in the Url insteed of "/" and this requires a configuration in HttpGet verb for the action

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources).

Something like this should get you where you want to be ...

```cs
[HttpGet("GetDepart")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Depart>> GetDepart([FromQuery] int id)
{
    //Return a Department
}
```

Notice the `[FromQuery]` attribute on the `id` parameter.

Comment: I configure the routing with the attribute [HttpGet("GetDepart/{id}")] but I have to put the URL with slash (/)
how can I replace [HttpGet ("GetDepart/{id}") to receive "?" instead of "/"

Answer (score 2):

HttpGetAttribute need template parameter,but template cannot contain the '?' character,it is by design.
So if you want to use `?id=1`,you can use like this(but this way is different from route,When http://localhost:44339/Departs/GetDepart it can also go to the action):

```
[HttpGet("GetDepart")]

    public async Task<ActionResult<Depart>> GetDepart(int id)
    {
        //Return a Department
    }
```

You don't need to add [FromQuery] before `int id`,model binding will find it in query string by default.You can refer to [official document of model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Agree, but in my opinion, GetDepart/{id} is better written for route

Comment: Thanks that works, and if the parameters is a Model then I use must use HttpGet or i must change it to HttpPost because the Model can't be sent in the url.